# Getting participants and turn from gamecenter match

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

I want to see in the menu of my game in which matches I'm currently participating. All games in my match have 2 players, you and your opponent. I don't get it done by the developer guide.

I have an array for all the matches that I'm currently in this loads when my player gets authenticated with game center:

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
    if (matches) {         
        thisMatch = matches[0];
    }
}
```

How would I get for example the opponent name of `matches[0]` and whose turn it is in that game, you or the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thisMatch.currentParticipant` would give you the `GKTurnBasedParticipant` whose turn is next.
To get the opponent's name, iterate over the `thisMatch.participants` and find the one whose `playerID` is not equal to your ID.